# Highlight specific Range containing Range

Tags: excel, vba

I have wrote a code to highlight the specific length of row i.e. `Sheet7.Range("C12:G12")` with `Sheet7.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`.

Where Sheet2.Range("A20") & Sheet2.Range("A21") & Sheet2.Range("A22") matches in Sheet7.Range("C:C")

but my code is not working. Your help will be appreciated over the problem.

```
Sub Formatting()

Dim rg As Range

endrow = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For Each cell In Range("C12:C" & endrow)
 If cell.Value = Sheet2.Range("A20") & Sheet2.Range("A21") & Sheet2.Range("A22") Then
  cell.Sheet7.Range("C12:G12").Interior.Color = RGB(192, 192, 192)

  End If
Next

End Sub
```

this code is just highlights the  `Sheet7.Range("C12:G12")` just this row. It should go further.

```
Sub Local_BACKGROUND()
    endrow = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For Each cell In Range("C12:C" & endrow)
  If Not IsError(Application.Match(cell.Value, Sheet2.Range("A20:A23"), 0)) Then
     Sheet7.Range("C12:G12").Interior.Color = RGB(192, 192, 192)
  End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: `Sheet2.Range("A20") & Sheet2.Range("A21") & Sheet2.Range("A22")` is equivalent to `"AlphaBetaDelta"`

Comment: Yes @BigBen you are right.

Comment: ^^ `cell.value = Sheet2.range("A20") OR ....`

Comment: `If Not Iserror(Applicatioin.Match(cell.Value, Sheet2.Range("A20:A23"),0)) Then`

Comment: Thank you for the solution both of you but still the code is not working i have edited the question with new code. Can you please look once again.

Comment: @Mento Your error is in the line after `If not(iserror...`. The variable `Cell` does not have a `Sheet7` property. Get rid of `Cell.` in the following line and see if it works. It should just read `Sheet7.Range("C2:G12").Interior.....`

Comment: Yes i have tried with Sheet7.Range("C12:G12").Interior.Color = RGB(192, 192, 192) but still the issue is same.

Comment: @Mento I just tried running your code in a sample workbook and it worked for me. One thing that I noticed is you have a typo in the word `Application`. (You spelled it Applicatioin). Was this just a typo in on this website, or is your code also incorrect?

Comment: Oh i did not noticed thank you but still there is issue that is it highlights just 12th row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Format Row Ranges

**A Quick Fix**

```
Option Explicit

Sub formatRowRangesQF()
    Dim EndRow As Long
    EndRow = Sheet7.Range("C" & Sheet7.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim dCell As Range
    For Each dCell In Sheet7.Range("C12:C" & EndRow)
        If IsNumeric(Application.Match(dCell.Value, _
                Sheet2.Range("A20:A22"), 0)) Then
            dCell.Resize(, 5).Interior.Color = RGB(192, 192, 192)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

**A More Serious Solution**

```
Sub formatRowRanges()
    ' Source
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = Sheet2.Range("A20:A22")
    ' Destination
    Dim drg As Range
    With Sheet7.Range("C12:G12")
        Dim LastRow As Long
        With .Cells(1)
            LastRow = .Offset(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row).End(xlUp).Row
            If LastRow < .Row Then Exit Sub
        End With
        Set drg = .Resize(LastRow - .Row + 1)
    End With
    ' Combine
    Dim trg As Range
    Dim rrg As Range
    Dim cValue As Variant
    For Each rrg In drg.Rows
        cValue = rrg.Cells(1).Value
        If Not IsError(cValue) Then
            If Len(cValue) > 0 Then
                If IsNumeric(Application.Match(cValue, srg, 0)) Then
                    If trg Is Nothing Then
                        Set trg = rrg
                    Else
                        Set trg = Union(trg, rrg)
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
    ' Color
    If Not trg Is Nothing Then
        drg.Interior.Color = xlNone
        trg.Interior.Color = RGB(192, 192, 192)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much code is working perfectly.

Comment: Thank you a lot again

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work because of the way you've set up your test condition. It will evaluate everything to the right of the `=` first, and then compare it to the cell value. This will result in (for example) `"alpah" = "alphabetagammadelta"`.

Try instead something like:

```
if not(iserror(Application.Match(cell.value, Sheet2.Range("A20:A23"), 0))
```

Comment: I have updated the @basodre modified code but still not working.